# How can I make x divs rather than a single div of x width using d3?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am attempting to present some data vaguely similarly to what is done in https://xkcd.com/980, though on a much smaller scale.

What I am attempting to do is separate each of the horizontal bars (the divs created in the enter() and append()) into a series of smaller blocks, according to the average of the total that they make up (d/d3.sum(data)*100).

I am using the d3 library, but I haven't seen an example that has attached code nor that does quite the same thing. My own attempts have either failed or are, to my knowledge of JavaScript and d3, not possible.

I've adapted a simple bar chart to be labeled by percentage rather than count, [here](http://codepen.io/blwc/pen/MwvmaV).

```
d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
  //can't enter and manipulate via loop?
    .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
  //or perhaps, using %age, use that to loop and make div?
    .text(function(d) { return Math.round(d/d3.sum(data)*100); });
```

I've also tried entering the div once it is created after assigning text, using d3's selectAll("div") followed by using the number in the array (.data(data[d])) and then entering and appending, but have been met with no luck.

Within the creation of the bars, where would I put a line creating inner div tags and how can I make sure that the correct amount are nested inside?

Comment: Erm, you need to re-write this question including some clear context and explanation of what you are trying and failing to do...

Comment: @CoolBlue thanks, first question, but you'd think I'd get how to phrase a question after using SO for so long

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not clear so I take a guess: is [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582) what you mean??